# Auth component with employee model; logging in without checking credentials

Tags: cakephp

Im trying to use Employee model instead of User model in Auth component. My code is:

**AppController**

```
public $components = array('Session','Auth');
function beforeFilter(){
    Security::setHash('md5');
    $this->Auth->userModel = 'Employee';
    $this->Auth->fields = array('username'=>'code','password'=>'password');
    $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller'=>'employees','action'=>'login');
    $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller'=>'pages','action'=>'home');
    $this->Auth->loginError = 'Invalid employee code or password, please try again';
    $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('controller'=>'employees','action'=>'login');
}
function beforeRender(){
    $this->set('Employee',$this->Auth->user());
}
```

**EmployeeController**

```
function login(){
    $this->layout = 'login';
}
function logout(){
    $this->Redirect($this->Auth->logout());
}
function beforeFilter(){
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->allow('signup');
}
function beforeRender(){
    parent::beforeRender();
}
```

**login.ctp**

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('Employee',array('/employees/login'));
echo $this->Form->input('code',array('label'=>'Employee code'));
echo $this->Form->input('password');
echo $this->Form->submit('Sign in',array('class'=>'b-button'));
echo $this->Form->end();
?>
```

The problem is, when i click the login button, page simply refreshes. No redirect, noerror messages, no nothing.

Is there any mistake in what im doing?

**EDIT**

```
function login(){
    $this->layout = 'login';
    if($this->request->is('post')){
        if($this->Auth->login($this->request->data)){
            $this->Redirect('/pages/home');
        }else{
            $this->Session->setFlash('incorrect');
        }
    }
}
function logout(){
    $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
}
```

Now its allowing logging in irrespective of the the employee code or password entered. In fact its alloing logging in even if login fields are empty.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
echo $this->Form->create('Employee', array('controller' => 'employees', 'action' => 'login'));
```

And also check the user authenticity in login method of your EmployeesController.php

```
public function login()
{       
    if ($this->request->is('post'))
    {
        if ($this->Auth->login($this->request->data))
        {               
         /*... do what you want...*/
        }
        else
        {
          this->Session->setFlash('Your username or password was incorrect.');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Should i explicitly write code in login action to check user authenticity? I heard Auth component does it automagically!

Comment: No, Auth only provide the facility to check the user automatically means you do not need to use the find query at all. you just have to use the $this->Auth->login() in if condition.

Comment: Now the login is working, but its allowing incorrect login also. Infact its allowing me to login even if i dont input emp code or password!

Comment: This is because of your Auth session is already set due to the first time correct login credential. Create a method logout and use $this->Auth->logout(). Then use. It will work fine for you.

Comment: I have the logout action and its doing its job fine. Once i logout using it, i cannot get into home page by directly entering url; i get redirected to login page. So that means its logggin out correctly, right? The problem is somewhere else i fear!

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $this->Form->create('Employee',array('/employees/login'));
```

Try:

```
echo $this->Form->create('Employee',array('action'=>'login'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue . Finally here is the solution.

a) Define the tablename and fileds inside $components. Dont use before filter

```
public $components = array('Session', 'Acl', 'Auth' => array('authenticate' => array('Form' => array('userModel' => 'Employee','fields' => array('username' => 'code'), 'password' => 'password'))), 'Cookie');
```

b)Never use

```
$this->Auth->login($this->request->data)
```

this creates session for whatever garbage u post.
Instead use

```
$this->Auth->login()
```

c) Also hashing method for cakephp is not md5. You may want to remove that line.